# GAE blobstore - programmatically upload files

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

I have created an application that will upload the users images to the blobstore, then perform some transformations on them. I need to save this new image to the blobstore. So far, I have resorted to using datastore blob types, however these have a maximum file size of 1MB.

Is there a way to programatically upload files to the blobstore without having to use a form and a POST event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, but [it is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobstorefiles).

Instead, as that doc says, you should write to Google Cloud Storage - you can still use the Blobstore to serve the files from there.